# Editing questions tagged 'rocks' or 'minerals' together with 'identification-request'?

Tags: discussion, tags, editing

I see people tagging identification questions with [identification-request](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification-request) *and* [rocks](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rocks) ([example](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/10222/can-anyone-tell-me-what-this-is)), or only with [rocks](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rocks).

Consider the following question counts:

- [66 tagged](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rocks+identification-request) tagged [rocks](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rocks) *and* [identification-request](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification-request)
- [105 tagged](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rocks) [rocks](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rocks)
- [39 tagged](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rocks+-identification-request) [rocks](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rocks) *without* [identification-request](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification-request)

Similar:

- [10 tagged](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minerals+identification-request) tagged [minerals](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minerals) *and* [identification-request](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification-request)
- [36 tagged](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minerals) [minerals](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minerals)
- [26 tagged](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minerals+-identification-request) [minerals](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minerals) *without* [identification-request](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification-request)

An identification question using only [rocks](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rocks) or [minerals](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minerals) misses the point, it's obvious that [identification-request](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification-request) needs to be edited in.

But what about the other way around?
**In an identification question should [rocks](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rocks) or [minerals](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minerals) be edited out?**
I doubt that people asking for identification know the difference.

Note that [rocks](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rocks) has no [usage guidance](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/tags/rocks/info) yet, [neither does minerals](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/tags/minerals/info).

Comment: Is there consensus that all [tag:identification-request]s must be about rocks?  Someone might want help to identify a type of cloud, seashell, coastline, or something else from the Earth.  [This highly upvoted identification-request](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/4366/6) is not about rocks, so I would say identification-request does not imply rocks.

Comment: I totally forgot that there are other things that need identification ;-)

Answer (score 4):

I think it is valuable to tag a question with both [rocks](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rocks) and [identification-request](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification-request).  Among the [most upvoted identification-request questions](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification-request), some have nothing to do with rocks:

- [What type of cloud formation is this?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/3045/what-type-of-cloud-formation-is-this)
- [What are these lake-like blue patches in the desert, visible in satellite image?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/4366/what-are-these-lake-like-blue-patches-in-the-desert-visible-in-satellite-image)

Although the [tag wiki](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/tags/identification-request/info) seems to assume identification requests are always about rocks, this is true for a majority but not for all cases.  I think the identification requests listed above are on-topic for our site, but clearly the guidelines on how to ask identification request questions are only relevant for rocks and minerals <sub>(I don't know the difference.)</sub>.

Certainly the tagging can use some maintenance.  Most [identification-request](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification-request) questions are about rocks or minerals, and most [rocks](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rocks) or [minerals](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minerals) questions are identification requests, but neither implies the other.  Therefore, I think we should use the tags independently.

Comment: I have updated the identification-request tag description